# Simpliest Propositional Equivalences proof question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm solving some propositional equivalences questions and I just want to make sure that following two logics.

If,

- $p \land q = q \land p$
- $p \vee q = q \vee p$

  - in any case, are correct because of the commutativity rule,

Than,

- $\neg p \vee \neg q = \neg q \vee \neg p$
- $\neg p \wedge \neg q = \neg q \wedge \neg p$

are correct as well?

I got most of the questions right by using them but I'm double checking it was not a luck.

It is so sad I don't know how to make a mathematical symbols since I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Click [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic MathJax primer on how to type with $\LaTeX$ on this site.  I expect you mean to use \vee, \wedge, and \neg for $\vee,\wedge$ and $\neg$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. The commutativity of $\land$ and $\lor$ tells us that for any $a, b$ we have that:
\begin{align*}
a \land b &= b \land a \\
a \lor b &= b \lor a
\end{align*}
In particular, taking $a = \neg p$ and $b = \neg q$ yields:
\begin{align*}
\neg p \land \neg q &= \neg q \land \neg p \\
\neg p \lor \neg q &= \neg q \lor \neg p
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok! just wanted to double check before test. I'm kind of cramming for exam tomorrow and probably nervous too much that started assuming things written in the textbook haha. THANKS A LOT!